# Percentage based height and width of jquery ui slider

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create an interface that is seamlessly responsive on all devices, and also resizes when its window is resized.

This example is getting there:

```
$('.resizer').resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    handles: 'all'
});

$("#slider").slider();
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SrPhA/426/)

The width and height of the slider element adjust dynamically as they are percentage based. But the handle stays the same! How can I allow the handle to resize with the slider? Will I have to root around in jquery-ui's css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweak the CSS properties:

```
.ui-slider-handle {
    top: -0.3em;
    margin-left: -0.6em;
}
.ui-slider-handle 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 0.2em;
    cursor: default;
}
```

If you want to do it dynamically you could try something like:

```
$('.ui-slider-handle').css('width',$('.lyr2').width()*0.1);
```

**Edit**:

Sorry, I did not get the resizing bit before. You will have to put the above `css()` changing statement somehow into a suitable resizing-event routine. Something like this:

```
$('.resizer').resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    handles: 'all',
    resize: function(ev,ui) {var siz=ui.element.width()*0.1;
    $('.ui-slider-handle').css({width:siz,height:siz} );
    }});
$("#slider").slider();
```

See here: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SrPhA/430/). Not perfect yet, as the `top` and `margin-left` properties still need to be adjusted, but I'll leave that to you. ;-)